# JS RegEx allow certain characters and a few character only when part of a specific sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

For quite a few hours I have been struggling with the following:

I want to use RegEx using JS to allow the following characters:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 -.,]*$/igm
```

However I would also want to allow 
 or 
, which means I would allow the character < & > and /, but only when in either of the two forms above (
 or 
).
I was playing with something like;

```
/^(<(?=br \/>|br\/>))*&/img
```

Clearly this is not working, and I cannot seem to figure out how to test in one line of code whether the user input (a string) contains just the allowed characters plus the extra characters(<,>,/) but only when used as (
 or 
).

Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use `/^(?:<br ?\/>|[a-zA-Z0-9 .,-])*$/`

Comment: Yes Wiktor, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?:<br ?\/>|[a-zA-Z0-9 .,-])*$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:<br ?\/>|[a-zA-Z0-9 .,-])*` - zero or more:

  - `<br ?\/>` - `<br`, an optional space, `/>`
  - `|` - or
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9 .,-]` - a letter, digit, space, dot, comma or hyphen
- `$` - end of string.